# How is memory allocated to a "class Base" if there is a attribute "Base b;" inside definition of the class?

Tags: java, memory, allocation

How is memory allocated when object of Base is created?

```java
class Base {

    Base b;
    int a;
    int c;

}
```

Whenever I try to think about memory allocation it's normally something like sum of size of all attributes.

Something like

```
Base = a + c;
```

With this logic

```
Base = Base + a + c;
```

Comment: No, that is not how it works. `b` is a reference variable, all it will contain is either `null` or a _pointer_ (a.k.a. reference) to an object of type `Base`, so all it needs is 4 bytes for the reference; it does not allocate memory for an object of type `Base`, because a reference is not the object itself.

Comment: I'll add some provisos on that: the size of references in Java have been measured empirically at around 8 bytes.  Each reference isn't just a pointer, it has some overhead associated with it.  Also all classes (even Object) require some overhead as well, also around 8 bytes.  So `new Base()` might allocate 8 + 8 + 4 + 4 = 24 bytes on the heap, give or take a particular JVM's implementation.